# Is it possible and how to upgrade an existing GCE VM OS?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, instance, upgrade

I have a GCE Virtual Machine with Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter OS and I need to upgrade to Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter OS. I have found suggestions on the internet but I didn't find a formal process to do this, only suggestions.

I only have tried doing the upgrade using the OS Installer in place, but after the restart step, the VM seems to crash because doesn't respond.

N/A

I have GCE VM Windows 2008 R2 DataCenter and I need to become in GCE VM Windows 2012 R2 DataCenter. The process that I tested seems to do the VM crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible and how to upgrade an existing GCE VM OS?

For Windows, this is not supported. There are a number of technical reasons, but the primary reason is licensing. Windows images are "Premium Images". Also, Google does not provide a method for "major" version upgrades. You need to create a new instance and copy/restore your data.